# Get latest travis build status of a repo through travis API

Tags: github, build, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I need to get the latest travis build status of a repo through their API. I need a behavior identical to that of build status badge i.e it shows passing when a "push" is passing, even if a newer "pull_request" is failing.

One way of achieving is to list all builds of a repo using [this](http://docs.travis-ci.com/api/#builds) and then traverse in reverse direction until I find a build which is not a pull requests and then check its status.

However, there must be a short way of doing it because the same behavior is used by build status badge. Traversing the builds every time just to get the last build status seems like a pain.

What is the API endpoint use by build status batch to directly get the last "push" build status of a repo?

Answer (score 5):

The easiest solution is to not use Travis API but the build status badge. The test "passing" or "failing" is embedded as text in the SVG image:

```
curl -s 'https://api.travis-ci.org/$USER/$REPO.svg?branch=$BRANCH' | grep pass
curl -s 'https://api.travis-ci.org/$USER/$REPO.svg?branch=$BRANCH' | grep fail
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless you know the build.id, the best way I think is to use the API you are referring to and pass in the query parameter `limit`. Something like this:

```
repo/{repository.id}/builds/builds?limit=1
repo/{+repository.slug}/builds/builds?limit=1
```

Response would still be an array but index 0 will be the most recent build. `limit` is not documented but it is used by Travis for their pagination.

Comment: you have one too many `builds` keyword in the request

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your question, I am looking to accomplish the same objective, [here](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/triggering-builds/) are some detailed examples of how the API should work. From that I derived the following steps to get the build status of a repository default branch using Travis CI. Below are detailed instructions:

### TLDR

```
travis status -r a-t-0/sponsor_example --com --token <your personal Travis token>
```

### Detailed instructions

1. Open a terminal and login to use the Travis Api. You can do that by first getting a Travis token, by login in with git from your terminal:

```
travis login --com --auto
```

2. If that does not work(returning `Not Found`), you should add a GitHub Token manually.
   Source: https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token

   2.1 To get this token, first [verify your github](https://docs.github.com/en/github/getting-started-with-github/verifying-your-email-address) email adress if you did not yet do that.

   2.2 Go to: https://github.com/settings/tokens

   2.3 Add a new token and select:

   2.3.1  repo control of private repositories

   2.3.2  admin:org control of orgs and teams, read and write org projects

   2.3.3  admin:repo_hook Full control of repository hooks

   2.3.4  admin:org_hook control of organization

   2.4 Write down the secret personal access token from github. It can have a form like: `1somelettersandsomenumbersordigitsandth4`

   2.5 Next, use this token to login to either the `--pro`, `--com` or `--org` account types of Travis using:

```
travis login --pro --github-token 1somelettersandsomenumbersordigitsandth4
travis login --com --github-token 1somelettersandsomenumbersordigitsandth4
travis login --org --github-token 1somelettersandsomenumbersordigitsandth4
```

That should return: `Successfully logged in as <your github username>!`.

2.6 Note there are three types of api call licenses: pro, com, org. This is visible in `travis status -h

2.7 To get your pro token:

```
travis token --pro
Your access token is <somepersonalprotoken>
```

2.8 To get your --org token:

```
travis token --org
Your access token is <somepersonalorgtoken>
```

2.9 To get your --com token:

```
travis token --com
Your access token is <somepersonalcomtoken>
```

3. **Export your travis token to terminal before running the tests with:**

```
COM_TRAVIS_TOKEN="<your secret travis pro/com token>"
```

4. Get the build status with:

```
travis status -r {your GitHub username}/{your repo name} --com --token $COM_TRAVIS_TOKEN
```

5. E.g.

```
travis status -r a-t-0/sponsor_example --com --token $COM_TRAVIS_TOKEN
```